# Как оптимизировать код по угадыванию чисел?

Tags: python, python-3.x, инспекция-кода

Пользователь вводит числа до тех пор, пока не угадает число из списка `myList`. Есть ли возможность оптимизировать код и (или) уменьшить количество строк кода?

```py
myList = [1, 2, 3]
while True:
    exit = 0
    num = int(input('Enter: '))
    if num in myList:
        exit = 1
    if exit == 1:
        break
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Углубляясь в минимизацию, можно избавиться вообще от тела цикла и всех переменных:

```py
while int(input('Enter: ')) not in [1, 2, 3]:
    pass
```

А если список большой и состоит полностью из последовательных целых чисел, можно заменить его на `range(1, 4)`

PS: учтите, что оптимизация производительности кода != уменьшению числа строк кода. И помимо этих двух качеств программы также важна наглядность, которая нередко идёт вразрез с лаконичностью кода. Если тема интересна, советую почитать "Совершенный Код" Стива Макконнелла или подобную литературу.

Answer (score 2):

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]

while True:
    num = int(input('Enter: '))
    if num in my_list:
        break
```